# change row color if condition is satisfied

Tags: css, laravel

So I want to change row color if:

```
endTime- current time= 10 Minutes --> yellow
endTime- current time= 2 Minutes --> red
```

I don't know what to do, this is my blade.php

```
@foreach($transactions as $transaction) 

                        <tr> 
                            <td>{{$transaction['id']}}</td> 
                            <td>{{$transaction['user_id']}}</td>
                            <td>{{$transaction['cara']}}</td>
                            <td>{{$transaction['start']}}</td>
                            <td>{{$transaction['end']}}</td>
                            <td>{{$transaction['total']}}</td>
                            <td><img src="fetch_image{{$transaction->id}}" class="img-thumbnail" width="75"/> </td>
                            <td>{{$transaction['status']}}</td> 
                            <td><a href="{{action('TransactionController@updateconfirmed', $transaction['id'])}}" class="btn btn-success">Konfirmasi</a></td> 
                            <td><a href="" class="btn btn-warning">Reminder</a></td>
                            <td><a href="" class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</a></td>
                        </tr>
                    @endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Calculate your diff time

```
$to = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:s:i', '2015-5-6 3:30:34');
$from = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:s:i', '2015-5-6 3:30:54');


$diff_in_minutes = $to->diffInMinutes($from); // Output: 20
```

In your `<tr>` tag, you can add your conditions
`<tr class="{{ ($diff_in_minutes == 2 ? 'red' : (($diff_in_minutes == 10 ? 'yellow' : '')) }}">`

Add your css as well
`.yellow { background-color: #ffff00 }`
`.red { background-color: #ff0000 }`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use like this

```
@if(time()-strttotime($transaction['end'])>600)
   <tr "yellow">
@elseif(time()-strttotime($transaction['end'])<120)
   <tr "red">
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace The Row Line

```
@if(strtotime('now') - strtotime($transaction['end']) >= 600)
   <tr style="background-color: yellow">
@elseif(strtotime('now') - strtotime($transaction['end']) <= 120)
   <tr style="background-color: red">
@endif
```